# Rails - Amazon minitest/unit (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, minitest

I have hosted one Ruby on Rails application on Amazon EC2. I am using Java SSH Client to connect the instance. When I go to my working directory on Amazon and trying to put `rails c` then it showing error `require': cannot load such file -- minitest/unit (LoadError)`. I don't know why I am not able to access rails console.

```
/usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- minitest/unit (LoadError)
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/test/unit/assertions.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/test/unit/testcase.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/test_case.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/console/app.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:304:in `initialize_console'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:152:in `load_console'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:27:in `start'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

I tried to solve this error by installing `gem install minitest-rails` but it throwing error

`ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/share/ruby/1.9/gems/1.9.1 directory.`

I tried to add two gems `gem 'turn' , '< 0.8.3'` and `gem 'minitest-rails` in my gemfile also and then push to AWS but not getting anything.

How to get rid of this error. I want to access my rails console. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which gem you are trying to install? Have you added that to your gem file ?

Comment: yes but not working anything. I try to add `gem 'turn' , '< 0.8.3'` also but that one also not working

Comment: @ArihantGodha actually I don't know why I am getting this error and what is the solution of that.

Comment: @ShreshttBhatt, have you resolved this problem?

Answer (score 1):

To get past this error I had to do both a "gem install minitest" and add "gem 'minitest'" to the project Gemfile. I came by this solution by reading the comments on [this open issue for Rails on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9256); you might find further solutions there until this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
group :test do
  gem 'turn', '< 0.8.3',
  gem 'minitest', '~> 5.0.5'
end
```

Correct me if I am wrong but I guess you are trying to install Cucumber. If not please specify your rails version and ruby version.

Comment: ok i am trying by the way I am using rails 3.2.13 and ruby 1.9.3p125

Comment: Not working. I am not trying to install cucumber. I just want to open my rails console on Amazon

Comment: also add gem mintest in the group if it is dependent.

Comment: Please add gem mintest to your gemfile this should resolve your issue

Comment: Just uninstall both the gems from the bundle and install it independently without the group there might be issue with the conflicts. Just see this issue https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3826

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32392/discussion-between-shreshtt-bhatt-and-arihant-godha)